# 108 Characters in SLComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, slcomposeviewcontroller

How come when you are using SLComposeViewController on iOS you only get 108 characters for your tweet instead of the usual 140?

Shown in the screenshot below... [image]

I am creating this SLComposeViewController using the following code...

```
- (IBAction)compose:(id)sender {
    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {
        SLComposeViewController *composeViewController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
        [composeViewController addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter_logo.png"]];
        [composeViewController setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
            if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultDone) {
                UIAlertView *success = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Your tweet was successfully posted!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [success show];
            }
            else {
                [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            }
        }];
        [self presentViewController:composeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
        UIAlertView *error = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Error" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [error show];
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the paper clip is a hint that the image is an attachment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out why this was happening.

I didn't realize that `[composeViewController addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter_logo.png"]];` was technically posting a link to a picture in the tweet, like, *http://pic.twitter.com/7Fsa2kadf* so that was taking up 32 characters in the tweet.

If I comment out that line of code it is at 140 characters.

Maybe apple will display a link in future updates.